# Boot from live usb with persistent option

Tags: virtualbox, live-usb

I have a "live cd" copied to a USB stick, which successfully boots on a PC, including the persistent that uses a casper-rw partition.
But now I wish to boot this, including the persistent option, in a virtualbox session. This way I can play and toy with the contents as guest while my host is my real system, after which I can take my USB stick to another PC (eg. work, visiting someone) and being able to boot up all my stuff there.